# Gradle sync failed: Access is denied

Tags: android

I have installed Android studio and i have created the new project but it is giving me the error:

```
Gradle 'MyApplication2' project refresh failed
Gradle sync failed: Access is denied
```

I have also run android studio as an administrator but it did not work. Please help me with this. How can I build the gradle and run the project.

Comment: Can you try clearing cache and restarting AS?

Comment: Yes, this worked for me...

Comment: Glad it did help you!

Comment: That is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is permission related issue. Then you can change the gradle path from C to D drive. it will fix the issue[image]

Comment: no idea why it still creating .AndroidStudio3.0 in C drive although I've set Gradle path to D drive as yours, any idea?

Comment: also set SDK location in D drive then try. Default location is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. you set it to D drive

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue recently when the gradle plugin release was updated to 5.1.1. which caused an error message "apollo\generatedIR\debug (Access is denied)".

In order to fix this I had to revert back to the previous gradle version which was 3.3.2 and I had to make sure that the zip file that is downloaded when the project syncs matched the 3.3.2 version.

Here is where to check the versions of the gradle builds: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

The changes I made where:

In the gradle (project) file change the classpath plugin to the previous version:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

Then in the gradle-wrapper.properties file change the distributionUrl to match the required gradle version.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Then resync your project. If it doesn't work double check your gradle files by going to the C:Users//.gradle/wrapper/dists folder and it should match the version on the web page above.

Comment: I had this exact problem with the exact same upgrade. Thanks, this saved a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder right click ->Properties->under Security tab on it check permission and allow all permissions.